# Best practices for e2e tests with remote resources

Tags: python, cloud, integration-testing, pytest

I'm refactoring some e2e tests that are failing often. Likely because I can never be sure that the resources written in step 1 and there for steps 2 and 3.

There is sort of a strict chain of logic, but each test is not atomic in any way. Im not looking for specific python style advice (but I'd be happy to take some advice on how best to use pytest for end to end testing)

Is there a best practice for creation, verification and deletion of remote resources in an end to end test?

The four tests do the following:

````
test_write_credentials_to_cloud #This one always works
test_get_credentials_from_cloud #This is the one that often fails
test_delete_credentials_from_cloud #sometimes this one fails
test_verify_credentials_deleted_in_cloud #this one never is the problem```
````

Answer (score 0):

During e2e testing it is often the case that you have to deal with credentials, 
clearly the test plan should never get these hardcoded, and when loading to make sure there are not text plain but have some form of encryption.

Ideally, all cloud resources should start with a clean state when initializing a test plan, or use case. After test execution, you may consider disposing of these resources, but this sometimes can get tricky. For example some cloud provider have a rate limit on deletion per second for various resources like buckets, API Gateway.

Find more practical examples of how to build manage and run e2e testing with AWS and Google Cloud Platform: [Cloud/serverless e2e testing](https://github.com/adrianwit/serverless_e2e)

You might be also find interesting [Devlopement automation](https://medium.com/@adrianwit/software-development-automation-e68b3bcc70c9)

Comment: Thank you! I resolved my issue by implementing fixtures, keeping my boilerplate as minimal as possible and using the yield function to clean up out of scope of the tests.